# Ipsec: Is it possible to use both pre-shared keys and pubkeys auth methods at the same time?

Tags: authentication, ipsec

So if we have a server configuration with local auth pubkeys and remove psk and at the same time for a client(initiator) a local auth psk and remote pubkey.
Something like this. 
Server -

```
  local {
     round = 1
     id = 10.3.72.136
     auth = pubkey
     certs = autom_server-cert.pem
   }
  remote {
     auth = psk
     id = %any
   }
```

Client:

```
  local:
    rounds:
    - id: 1
      authentication-method: pre-shared-keys
      secret: test
  remote:
    rounds:
    - id: 1
      authentication-method: pubkeys
      ca-cert: /etc/swanctl/x509ca/autom-ca-cert.pem
      cert: /etc/swanctl/x509/autom_server-cert.pem
```

Can I initiate a connection ?
I have already configured them with psk or pubkeys both but I need to do it together. The error in the syslog from charon is:

Jun 06 07:48:50 server-automation-4 charon[11485]: 12[CFG] looking for pre-shared key peer configs matching 10.3.72.136...10.3.72.27[10.3.72.27]

Jun 06 07:48:50 server-automation-4 charon[11485]: 12[IKE] found 1 matching config, but none allows pre-shared key authentication using Main Mode

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with IKEv2, which allows the use of individual authentication methods for each peer (they are not negotiated, each peer indicates the used method in the `AUTH` payload, or via its absence to request EAP authentication).

But it's **not** possible with IKEv1, which you are apparently using, as there a single authentication method is negotiated between the peers (there are some combined-modes like XAuth/RSA, or hybrid authentication, but these are still negotiated as a single authentication method that both have to agree upon).

Comment: I have already tried that and the logs say the same thing but this time from the initiator - He can't even start the connection.

Jun 06 14:52:59 standardpci440fxpiix1996525400bb9d4d charon[22450]: 05[IKE] IKE_SA conn-vti0[279] state change: CREATED => CONNECTING

Jun 06 14:52:59 standardpci440fxpiix1996525400bb9d4d charon[22450]: 05[CFG] configuration uses unsupported authentication

Jun 06 14:52:59 standardpci440fxpiix1996525400bb9d4d charon[22450]: 05[IKE] IKE_SA conn-vti0[279] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING

Comment: Tried what exactly? As I said, you can't mix PSK with pubkey authentication when using IKEv1.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I have already tried using IKEv2 that is a log from the initiator while using IKEv2

Comment: It is not! That log message is only produced by strongSwan's IKEv1 subsystem, so you apparently didn't change the version.